# Powershell - Convert an ordered nested dictionary to html

Tags: html, powershell, dictionary

I need to report the number of VM snapshots based on their age. For this, I constructed an ordered dictionary that contain another dictionary like this (json output):

```
{
  "Less than 24h": {
    "Prod": 15,
    "Other": 11
  },
  "1 day": {
    "Prod": 29,
    "Other": 12
  },
  "2 days": {
    "Prod": 11,
    "Other": 0
  },
  "3 days and more": {
    "Prod": 0,
    "Other": 0
  }
}
```

I need to convert it to html to be included in a mail.
I find how to convert a "simple" dictionary :

```
$Body1 = $dict.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object Key,Value | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment | Out-String
$Body1 = $Body1.Replace('Key','Days').Replace('Value','Number of Snapshot')
```

And that work fine, but not if the values are nested dictionaries.
For nested dictionary the output will be like this :

```
| Days            | Number of Snapshot                             |
|-----------------|------------------------------------------------|
| Less than 24h   |`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`| 
| 1 day           |`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`|
| 2 days          |`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`|
| 3 days and more |`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`|
```

Is there a way to have a html output like this?

```
| Days            | Prod | Other |
|-----------------|------|-------|
| Less than 24h   |  15  |   11  | 
| 1 day           |  29  |   12  |
| 2 days          |  11  |    0  |
| 3 days and more |   0  |    0  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to pre-process your dictionary and convert it into something else that can be turned into html a bit easier:

```
$data = $dict.GetEnumerator() | foreach-object {
    new-object pscustomobject -property ([ordered] @{
        "Days"  = $_.Key
        "Prod"  = $_.Value.Prod
        "Other" = $_.Value.Other
    })
}
```

This will flatten your nested structure into this json-equivalent:

```json
[
  {
    "Days": "2 days",
    "Prod": 11,
    "Other": 0
  },
  {
    "Days": "1 day",
    "Prod": 29,
    "Other": 12
  },
  {
    "Days": "Less than 24h",
    "Prod": 15,
    "Other": 11
  },
  {
    "Days": "3 days and more",
    "Prod": 0,
    "Other": 0
  }
]
```

And then you can just convert the whole thing in one go without `-Fragment`:

```
$Body1 = $data | ConvertTo-Html
```

which gives:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Days</th><th>Prod</th><th>Other</th></tr>
<tr><td>2 days</td><td>11</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 day</td><td>29</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>Less than 24h</td><td>15</td><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td>3 days and more</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

or

| Days | Prod | Other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 days | 11 | 0 |
| 1 day | 29 | 12 |
| Less than 24h | 15 | 11 |
| 3 days and more | 0 | 0 |

Comment: @KarimKanoun - No worries. Btw, it's better if you wait a while before accepting an answer in case a better one comes along. One you've marked an answer you'll generally get less people clicking through to read your question...

Comment: I accepted because I tried it in my script and I receive the mail like I wanted it to be :). But one thing : `-Frangment` is mandatory because `$Body1` is a part of the HTML, and I kept it in my code and all works perfectly.